# Truffle console is hanging on function call

Tags: truffle, metamask, ganache

I have a contract deployed to [ropsten](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xFB2028CD4f112d0907251d6AF7Ab70970Fe69cc4). It has a function called `enter`:

```
    function enter() public payable {
        assert(msg.value == MINIMUM);
        assert(OPEN == true);
        players.push(msg.sender);
    }
```

It pushes a player onto an array. I want to call this function with (using `truffle console --network live` where `live` is pointing to ropsten):

```
let lottery = await Lottery.deployed()
lottery.enter({from: accounts[0], value: 1000000000000000000})
```

However, it ends up just hanging, and I see no action on Etherscan.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you sure ```accounts[0]``` is not null?

Comment: How can I check if it's null? The address looks correct. `accounts[0]` returns the correct address.